# How to get the 'To' address value from a Zend_Mail Object

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a `Zend_Mail` Object.

Is there any way to get the `To` address value from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the getRecipients() method:

```
$mailObj->getRecipients();
```

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail.html#getRecipients